# Conjugating by an upper triangular matrix does not change the diagonal entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49679/a-matrix-similarity-problem makes the claim that conjugating by an upper triangular matrix does not change the diagonal entries.  But how do I prove this for all n x n matrices?

Also, what about the converse.  Suppose A,B,C are invertible matrices and $ABA^{-1} = C$ where $B$ and $C$ have the same diagonal.  Must it be the case that $A$ is triangular?

Answer (score 1):

The linked Mathoverflow question doesn’t claim that conjugation of *any* matrix by an upper triangular matrix preserves the diagonal, and such interpretation would be, in fact, not true.

On the other hand, conjugation of the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) by any invertible matrix gives also the identity matrix. Not to say the zero matrix also gives zero matrices under any multiplications.

So, −1.

Answer (score 0):

the considered result is true only if the first matrix is also triangular.